# Recursive Implementation of Binary Search in Java

Tags: java, binary-search

I am trying to an implementation of the binary search in Java recursively.

I came up with this and it only returns -1. However, I do not understand why this is the only result no matter what array I use.

Array Example: array int =  {1, 6, 7, 9, 11 , 16};

Call Example: recursiveBinarySearch(array, 7, array.length, 0);

```
public static int recursiveBinarySearch(int array[], int key, int high, int low) {
    
    int mid = (high + low) / 2;
    int middleNumber = array[mid];
        
    if (key == middleNumber )
        return mid; 
    else if (low > high)
        return -1;
        
    else {
        if (middleNumber > key) {
            high = mid - 1; 
            recursiveBinarySearch(array, key, high, low);
        }
        
        else {
            low = mid + 1; 
            recursiveBinarySearch(array, key, high, low);
        }
        
    }
    
    return -1;
    
}
```

Comment: Could you please complete your code with an example array and how you call the function?

Comment: the only `return` from posted code is `-1` unless the value is found right at the start - what is happening with the values returned by the recursive calls? I recommend to remove the last `return -1;` - that one should never happen...

Comment: How did you try to debug your code?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Recursive function in Java prints correct value but returns wrong one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74755285/recursive-function-in-java-prints-correct-value-but-returns-wrong-one)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return the value from each recursive call and remove the last `return -1;` statement

```
int[] array = {1, 6, 7, 9, 11 , 16};
for (int target : new int[] {3, 7}) {
   int index = recursiveBinarySearch(array, target, array.length, 0);
   System.out.println(index >= 0 ? array[index] : "Target not found!");
}
```

prints

```
Target not found!
7
```

```
public static int recursiveBinarySearch(int array[], int key, int high, int low) {
    
    int mid = (high + low) / 2;
    int middleNumber = array[mid];
        
    if (key == middleNumber )
        return mid;
    else if (low > high)
        return -1;
        
    else {
        if (middleNumber > key) {
            high = mid - 1; 
            return recursiveBinarySearch(array, key, high, low);
        }
        
        else {
            low = mid + 1; 
            return recursiveBinarySearch(array, key, high, low);
        }    
    }
}
```